# jQuery class check on mouseup

Tags: jquery, drupal-7, draggable

I have the following code which works when detecting mousedown and mouseup. The problem begins within mouseup where I am trying to check if the target element has a certain class.

The code within the if-statement never executes.

```
$(this).find('td:first a.tabledrag-handle').mousedown(
    function(){
                        
        $(this).mouseup(
            function(){
                console.log('mouseup detected');
                                    
                $(this).parents('tr').css('background', 'red');
                                    
                if( $(this).parents('tr').hasClass('drag-previous') ){
                    console.log('Dragged');
                    $(this).parents('tr').css('background', 'blue');
                }
            }
        );
    }
);
```

The *if( $(this).parents('tr').hasClass('drag-previous') ) ...* code never executes.

Is there a better technique or work around to solve this problem?

### Update

What I'm trying to achieve is detecting drag-&-drop events on the following table. I need to read the weight for each row as generated by the dragging and set that figure in the 'custom weight' field and save the custom weight.

[image]

That needs to take place for each individual row and that's why I am detecting mousedown and mouseup on the cross-hairs instead on mousein or out on the row, for example.

Comment: Post your HTML, or provide jsfiddle.net

Comment: Why are you delegating mouseup inside mousedown?

Comment: @Anton: I am trying to detect a drag-&-drop event provided by a different script

Comment: Better to create a bool variable or data-attribute for that then. Otherwise it will create multiple mouseup functions everytime you mousedown on the same element.

Answer (score 0):

### Use mouseenter and mouseleave event

```
window.jQuery('table tr').find('td:first a.tabledrag-handle').mouseenter(function () {
    window.jQuery(this).parents('tr').css('background', 'red');
});


window.jQuery('table tr').find('td:first a.tabledrag-handle').mouseleave(function () {
    if (window.jQuery(this).parents('tr').hasClass('drag-previous')) {
        console.log('Dragged');
        window.jQuery(this).parents('tr').css('background', 'blue');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I've explained in an update why this would not work

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the mouseup event directly. Dont have to put under mousedown

```
$("td:first a.tabledrag-handle").mouseup(function (e) {
            $(this).parents("tr").css('background', 'red');
            if ($(this).parents("tr").hasClass('drag-previous')) {
                console.log('Dragged');
                $(this).parents('tr').css('background', 'blue');
            }
        });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/S38AH/3/)

If you want to check td's in each row, change the selector like this

```
$("tr td:first-child").mouseup(function (e) {
                $(this).parents("tr").css('background', 'red');
            if ($(this).parents("tr").hasClass('drag-previous')) {
                console.log('Dragged');
                $(this).parents('tr').css('background', 'blue');
            }
        });
```

[**UpdatedFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/S38AH/4/)

Comment: Thanks however I tried your approach but it didn't work. I have given further detail in an update to my question.